# looping through a string and dynamically inserting attributes vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through a string of HTML content.

Looping through all the headers and injecting an id tag of its text dynamically.

I'm doing this on the server side (nodejs), so it limits what I can use or want to use without adding any extra libraries just to do this one thing. eg. Jquery, domParser

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? all in one loop?

```js
let str = "<h1>abc</h1><h2>xyz</h2><h3>aaa</h3><h1>aaaaa</h1>";

if (str.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g) !== null) {
  const h1Arr = str.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g).map(val => {
    return val.replace(/<\/?h1>/g, '');
  });

  str = str.replace(/<h1>/g, function() {
    return `<h1 id="${h1Arr.shift().replace(" ", "_")}">`;
  });
}

if (str.match(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/g) !== null) {
  const h2Arr = str.match(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/g).map(val => {
    return val.replace(/<\/?h2>/g, '');
  });

  str = str.replace(/<h2>/g, function() {
    return `<h2 id="${h2Arr.shift().replace(" ", "_")}">`;
  });
}

if (str.match(/<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/g) !== null) {
  const h3Arr = str.match(/<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/g).map(val => {
    return val.replace(/<\/?h3>/g, '');
  });

  str = str.replace(/<h3>/g, function() {
    return `<h3 id="${h3Arr.shift().replace(" ", "_")}">`;
  });
}

console.log(str)
```

Comment: how would you handle nested tags?

Comment: unless you want to write dom parser yourself, i'd say use something like jsdom, a external library for nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

While I'd highly not recommend creating custom parsers for xml or html, there are many edge cases to deal with. There is a way to simplify your code as is.

```
let str = "<h1>abc</h1><h2>xyz</h2><h3>aaa</h3><h1>aaaaa</h1>",
    r = new RegExp(/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/\1?>/mgi),
    res,
    new_str = "";

while (res = r.exec(str)) {
  new_str += compose(...res);
}

function compose(str, tag, text) {
  let cut = str.substr(tag.length + 1);
  return `<${tag} id="${text}"${cut}`;
}

console.log(new_str);
```